# How to find() a document when some subdocument array record is before date 'X'

Tags: mongodb

I'm stuck (again) with a mongoDB query.
It must be simple, but I can't find it out...

Let's say I have a collection/document like this one:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("588055a656f0dc1c9327eaf9"),
  type: "house",
  timeline: [
    {
      action: "abc",
      date: 2017-01-01,
    },
    {
      action: "xyz",
      date: 2016-12-12,
    }
   ]
}
```

I would like to query only docs with type `house` and where action `xyz` is before - let's say - `2015`... How to do so?

Obviously, I know how to query by `type`...

```
db.collection().find({ 'type': 'house' }).toArray()
```

I also know how to query with `dot.notation`

```
db.collection().find({ 'timeline.action': 'xyz' }).toArray()
```

But how to build a query where action `xyz` is before - let's say - `2015`?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Try something like `db.collection.find({'timeline':{action: 'xyz', 'date':{$lt: "2015-01-01" }}}`

Comment: Thanks, but it will (I think) not work. Because I have multiple `timeline.date` and I want to get only those where `date` is before `some date` **for** `action XYZ`.. But I might be missing something... EDIT : Get it! I was missing some {}... Thank you very much. So simple.

Comment: Be careful with this kind of query on subelements.
It falls into a weird syntactic place in mongo due to how data is saved.
Sometimes it will not return what is expected.
http://devblog.me/wtf-mongo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `$elemMatch` operator to match on the embedded fields. (missed that operator in the comment)

```
db.collection.find({'timeline': {$elemMatch:{action: 'xyz', 'date':{$lt: "2015-01-01"}}}})
```

More here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#array-of-embedded-documents

Answer (score 1):

Use $match to find type condition, and $redact for  getting only matched 'timeline'  objects ,

```
      db.collection.aggregate([{$match:{type:"house"}},{
        $redact: {
            "$cond": [{
                $and: [{
                    "$eq": [{
                            "$ifNull": ["$action", "xyz"]
                        },
                        "xyz"
                    ]
                }, {
                    "$lte": [{
                            "$ifNull": ["$date", ISODate("2015-01-01T00:00:02.015Z")]
                        },
                       ISODate("2015-01-01T00:00:02.015Z")
                    ]
                }]
            }, "$$DESCEND", "$$PRUNE"]
        }
    }]).pretty()
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to be careful with this kind of match because of the way mongo saves data.

If you query

```
{
    action: 'xyz',
    date: {$lt: '2015-01-01'}
}
```

but your object is saved as

```
{
    date: {$lt: '2015-01-01'},
    action: 'xyz'
}
```

then mongo will not match due to the underlying structure of the saved data.

If you need to match on multiple elements it it recommended to use $elemMatch.

```
{timeline : {
    $elemMatch: {
        action: 'xyz', 
        date: {$lt: '2015-01-01'}
    }
}}
```

as it will match on each element, not the object as a whole.

Your total query should look something like

```
{
    type: 'house'
    timeline : {
        $elemMatch: {
            action: 'xyz', 
            date: {$lt: '2015-01-01'}
        }
    }
}
```